# Perl numeric variables

Tags: perl, numeric, variable-types

Perl and I disagree as to whether a variable is a number or not.  I'm wrong, of course, but why?

```
my $bytes = 0;
# . . .
$bytes = $bytes + length($text);
# . . .
my $MB = $bytes / 1048576;
my $string = sprintf("Downloaded: %.1f MB\n", MB);
```

gives `Argument "MB" isn't numeric in sprintf at foo.pl line 200.`.

It is, in fact, numeric as can be seen when I use

```
my $string = "Downloaded: $MB MB\n";
```

which sets the string to `Downloaded: 3.09680080413818 MB`.

Edit: Ah, silly mistake, thanks for catching it.

Comment: As @Wooble pointed out, you can catch some of these in the future with `use strict;` (and I would add that you should also `use warnings;`).

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Absolutely.  I always _intend_ to use them... thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the variable sigil:

```
my $bytes = 0;
# . . .
$bytes = $bytes + length($text);
# . . .
my $MB = $bytes / 1048576;
my $string = sprintf("Downloaded: %.1f MB\n", $MB);   # <--- note the $MB at the end
```

Comment: This is why you should always `use strict;`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you probably meant:

```
my $string = sprintf("Downloaded: %.1f MB\n", $MB);
```

other than that this should work.